# Group data by rep, fit model, and integrate curve

Tags: r, dplyr, modelr

I have a series of points over time and I want to fit a curve to these points and then find the area under the curve. I can do it like this:

```
fit<-loess(mass ~ hour, df)
f <- function(x) predict(fit,newdata=x)
answer<-integrate(f, 0, 60)$value
```

So far, so good, but my problem is that I have replications of the points. I want a fit and a value for each replication.

```
trt    rep    hour    mass
y      a      1       3
y      a      2       5
y      a      3       8
y      a      4       6
y      b      1       2
y      b      2       3
y      b      3       5
y      b      4       4
n      c      1       4
n      c      2       6
n      c      3       8
n      c      4       7
n      d      1       5
n      d      2       7
n      d      3       8
n      d      4       7
```

I want to `dplyr::group_by(rep)`, but the grouping doesn't come through to `fit`. I'm could also do grouping in `nlme` and use `nlsList`, but the package doesn't work well with `loess` or polynomials in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like case for `do()`. With your sample data

```
dd <- read.table(text="trt    rep    hour    mass
y      a      1       3
y      a      2       5
y      a      3       8
y      a      4       6
y      b      1       2
y      b      2       3
y      b      3       5
y      b      4       4
n      c      1       4
n      c      2       6
n      c      3       8
n      c      4       7
n      d      1       5
n      d      2       7
n      d      3       8
n      d      4       7 ", header=T)
```

and your area calculation

```
get_area <- function(df) {
    fit <- loess(mass ~ hour, df)
    f <- function(x) predict(fit,newdata=x)
    integrate(f, 0, 60)$value  
}
```

you can just run

```
dd %>% group_by(rep) %>% do(area=get_area(.))
```